# Using process.start to launch the default program for a file does not allow further control of process

Tags: vb.net, process

I am trying to get my application to launch an MPG file in whatever application the user has set as their default player. I can do this by using:

```
Dim movie as Process = Process.Start("movie.mpg")
```

However I also need to know when the user has finished watching the video and has closed the default player application. For this I would normally use `movie.HasExited` but this returns `Object reference not set to instance of object`

I'm guessing the cause is that vb does not know what process was launched by windows as a result of opening an MPG file?

If so, how can I get my application to open the default (user defined) media player and still control the process?

Thanks

Comment: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That doesn't really help.

Comment: Can you post a bit more code.  Where are you calling movie.HasExited?  Your moive object may be out of scope.